# I messed up my desktop horribly

Tags: python, 17.04

Basically I was trying to completely remove Python from my raspberry pi so I ram "sudo apt remove python*" but apparently the network connection dropped before I ran the command and I don't notice, so instead of running the command on the pi it ran on Ubuntu and after I noticed I immediately quit the terminal to prevent further damage, and I rebooted and now the only thing on my desktop is my files. Is there a list of all programs that are installed by default? I really don't want to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: You might get away with doing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` which will install all default packages. It's possible the Gnome terminal can still be used with ctrl+alt+t or the tty with ctrl+alt+F2. Python is an essential package, don't uninstall it. Even on your Pi.

Comment: Yep. I now realize how retarded I can be sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/apt/` will have some helpful records of what was done, so you can reinstall.